# Subscribing/unsubscribing multiple Subscriptions with a Subscriber

Tags: rx-java

I can't find a clear explanation of how RxJava `Subscriber`s handle multiple `Subscription`s. (Comments refer to RxJava 1.x)

`Subscriber` has an `add( Subscription )` method, which "adds the `Subscription` to the `Subscriber`'s list of `Subscription`s", with no further explanation. What are the rules as to which `Subscription`s may take part?

Interestingly, both `Subscriber` and `Subscription` have an `unsubscribe()` method. Presumably `subscriber.unsubscribe()` will unsubscribe the entire `Subscription` list, while `subscription.unsubscribe()` will only cancel that one `Subscription`, though I can't find this stated anywhere. Is this correct?

I haven't dived into RxJava 2.x yet; are there any changes to this (other than `Subscription` being renamed `Disposable`)?

Answer (score 0):

To bring some light into this, and understand also better the subscriber and subscription I made this example

```
/**
 * In every moment we have the possibility to create our own subscriber, which you have to implement ActionSubscriber
 *  with onNext, onError and onComplete functions.
 *  Once that you do that you can attach that subscriber into a subscription.
 *  
 *  You can also can add the subscription into a subscriptionList that a subscriber has to know the state of the
 *  subscriptions where he is part of
 */
@Test
public void subscriberAndSubscription() {
    Integer[] numbers = {0, 1, 2};

    Subscriber subscriber = new ActionSubscriber(number -> {
        try {
            Thread.sleep(500);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        System.out.println("Subscriber number:" + number);
    },
            System.out::println,
            () -> System.out.println("Subscriber End of pipeline"));

    Subscription subscription = Observable.from(numbers).subscribeOn(Schedulers.newThread()).subscribe(subscriber);
    Subscription subscription1 = Observable.from(numbers).subscribeOn(Schedulers.newThread()).subscribe(subscriber);

    subscriber.add(subscription);
    subscriber.add(subscription1);
    System.out.println("Is Unsubscribed??:" + subscriber.isUnsubscribed());


    new TestSubscriber((Observer) subscription)
            .awaitTerminalEvent(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

    System.out.println("Is Unsubscribed??:" + subscriber.isUnsubscribed());

}
```

As I understand the         `subscriber.add(subscription);` is a mechanism to control the number of subscription where my subscriber is part of it, and the state of those subscriptions. so then I can know when all my subscriptions has finish to emit and unsubscribed me.

I made some examples here https://github.com/politrons/reactive/blob/master/src/test/java/rx/observables/creating/ObservableSubscription.java

Answer (score 0):

`Subscriber.add()` is utilized internally by RxJava 1 to associate resources, such as `Scheduler.Worker`s, other `Subscriber`s and actions that have to be unsubscribed/executed when the `Subscriber` is unsubscribed or completes.

`Subscriber.unsubscribe()` is there because `Subscriber` is also a `Subscription` that allows them to be chained together and added to each other for the cleanup routine mentioned above.

Internally, `Subscriber` has a list of `Subscription`s that can be unsubscribed together.

As an end consumer of the RxJava API, you don't have to worry about `add()`. However, exposing this resource-container logic to the public and burdening all `Subscriber`s with it was not the ideal solution. 2.x has changed the architecture to [overcome this property](https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJava/wiki/What's-different-in-2.0#subscription).

In 2.x, the `Disposable` interface takes the role of the `Subscription` interface, but the default `Observer` no longer hosts resources. It is the upstream's responsibility to do that. However, to support the old resource-container behavior, a separate abstract class [`ResourceObserver`](http://reactivex.io/RxJava/2.x/javadoc/io/reactivex/observers/ResourceObserver.html) has been introduced.

Comment: Thanks, that helps. Just to be clear, is it true that (in RxJava 1.x): (1) `subscription.unsubscribe()` cancels just that one `Subscription`, while (2) `subscriber.unsubscribe()` cancels all `Subscription`s in the `Subscriber`'s list?

Comment: Why do you thing `subscription.unsubscribe()` would know about any other `Subscription` instances?

Comment: That's not really the issue. The issue is: is it possible to unsubscribe a single `Subscription` of a `Subscriber` while leaving the rest active?

Comment: No. You have to store it separately beyond `add` and then unsubscribe that specific instance.

Comment: Which prompts another question: if `mySubscriber.unsubscribe()` cancels all `Subscription`s in the list, and if `someSubscription` is one of those `Subscription`s, what does `someSubscription.unsubscribe()` do?

Comment: Nothing. `unsubscription()` is idempotent and `mySubscriber.unsubscribe()` has already unsubscribed that particular instance as well.

Comment: I meant, what happens if you call `someSubscription.unsubscribe()` *without* calling `mySubscriber.unsubscribe`? Will it just cancel that one `Subscription` and leave the rest of the ones on mySubscriber's list active?

Comment: I suggest you write a test to find it out.